# Host ' ' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on client/server side in android. And create a php file which contains only these lines of code:

```
mysql_connect("192.184.10.45");  //line#3
mysql_select_db("Test_Data");
$sql=mysql_query("select * from registeration ");
mysql_close();
```

When I run this on browser then this give me these messages:

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Host '  ' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project1\server.php on line 3

Comment: Seems pretty self-explanatory - check that your MySQL server allows remote access from your webserver box

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass username and password also here

```
mysql_connect("192.184.10.45","username","password"); //line#3
```

And stop using `mysql_*` functions they are deprecating, use instead `Mysqli` OR `PDO`.

Comment: in username i gave my system username and in pass i gave my system pass but its not working still

Comment: @User42590 Is `192.184.10.45` your current system? If yes then use `localhost`. If not then use that system's `mysql's` username and password.

Comment: i am new in mysql connectivity so don't know much about it so i don't know what will be the username and pass of mysql. So how to know it

Comment: @User42590 Is `192.184.10.45` your current system?

Comment: 192.184.10.45 is system's ip and name of my computer is "User_1" so when error occurs it prints :Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Host 'User_1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project1\server.php on line 3

Comment: @User42590 I knows 192.184.10.45 is system's ip. But is it your current system or remote system?

Comment: Use username as `root` and password as `root` OR `empty password`.